# Manipulating displayed value and committedValue on core-input

Tags: polymer

I need to manipulate values from a raw API data for display to the user and manipulate them again before sending the update through the API.  I'm using core-input for each value, but I'm having difficulty setting the initial value and binding to the correct update event.

```
<input id="host" is="core-input">
```

My first problem is that I don't know how to set and manipulate the initial `value` without also binding to the live changes stream.  I tried binding only to `committedValue` but it does not set the initial value for the field.

However, even when I set `commitedValue`, I am unable to trigger it.  I enter text into the field and then switch fields or press the enter key and nothing happens.

```
<input id="host" commitedValue="{{record | setHost}}" is="core-input">
```

And the JavaScript:

```
  setHost: {
    toDOM: function(record) {
      if(record.host === "@"){
        return record.domain;
      } else {
        return record.host + "." + record.domain;
      }
    },
    toModel: function(value) {
      if(record.host === "@"){
        return record.domain;
      } else {
        return record.host + "." + record.domain;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the initial value, I think you can do a one-time binding.

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <input is="core-input" type="text" value="[[foo]]">
</template>

<script>
  var tmpl = document.querySelector('template');
  tmpl.foo = 'bar';
</script>
```

It seems like the approach you're trying to take with `commitedValue` may not be supported, because you can't actually write to `commitedValue`.

[From the core-input docs on commitedValue](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-input.html#core-input.attributes.committedValue)

> Setting this property has no effect on the input value.

It might be better to listen to `on-change` or `on-blur` (or both), handle the change, and then manually update `value`

Comment: This just feels like it goes against the design philosophy of Polymer.  Perhaps we should move this discussion to a Github ticket or a mailing list?

Comment: Which part feels like it's going against the design philosophy?  *edit* if you'd prefer you can send a message to polymer-dev. Might be easier for long form discussion as you mentioned